# Having trouble returning function in custom React hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-hooks

I am currently trying to create a `useRadioList()` hook that keeps track of an `isExpanded` prop on all the children in a given component (When one child toggles `isExpanded`, the other children un-toggle)

The way I've gone about doing this has been to:

1. Setup initial state by creating a list of false values with the same length as children
2. Map this state to each child's `isExpanded` prop
3. Declare and return a toggle function that manipulates the state of the initial list

```
// useRadioList.jsx
import React, { Children, isValidElement, cloneElement, useState, useEffect } from "react"

export default (children, allowMultiple = true) => {


// 1) Setup initial list 

  const [radioList, setRadioList] = useState(Array(children.length).fill(false))

// 2) Map radioList values to component children on initial render, and do so again if radioList changes

  useEffect(() => {

    Children.map(children, (child, idx) => {
      if (!isValidElement(child)) {return}

      return cloneElement(child, {isExpanded: radioList[idx]})
    })
  }, [radioList])



// 3) Declare "toggle()" to modify the list that keeps track of what indexes are active

  const toggle = (targetIndex) => {

    let newList = radioList.map((item, idx) => {
      if (allowMultiple) {
        return targetIndex == idx ? !item : item
      } else {
        return targetIndex == idx ? !item : false
      }
    })
    setRadioList(newList)
  }

  return toggle
}

// expected:  const toggle = useRadioList(children)
```

When I call toggle I get the following error:

> Warning: State updates from the useState() and useReducer() Hooks
>   don't support the second callback argument. To execute a side effect
>   after rendering, declare it in the component body with useEffect().

**Edit:**

`setRadioList(...newList) ----> setRadioList(newList)`

No longer getting the `callback` error, it seems now I am having trouble effectively mapping state to children as the `isExpanded` prop does not show up in each child after the initial render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that manipulate the children, does not mutate the original children, but create new one, so the following code has no effect :

```
   Children.map(children, (child, idx) => {
      if (!isValidElement(child)) {return}

      return cloneElement(child, {isExpanded: radioList[idx]})
    });
```

Try returning the new children, something like this :

```
export default (originalChildren, allowMultiple = true) => {


  // 1) Setup initial list 

    const [radioList, setRadioList] = useState(Array(originalChildren.length).fill(false))
    const [children, setChildren] = useState(originalChildren);

  // 2) Map radioList values to component children on initial render, and do so again if radioList changes

    useEffect(() => {
      setChildren(children => Children.map(children, (child, idx) => {
        if (!isValidElement(child)) {return}

        return cloneElement(child, {isExpanded: radioList[idx]})
      }));

    }, [radioList])



  // 3) Declare "toggle()" to modify the list that keeps track of what indexes are active

    const toggle = useCallback((targetIndex) => {
      setRadioList(radioList => radioList.map((item, idx) => {
        if (allowMultiple) {
          return targetIndex == idx ? !item : item
        } else {
          return targetIndex == idx ? !item : false
        }
      }))
    }, [allowMultiple])

    return { toggle, children }
  }

  // use like this:  const { toggle, children } = useRadioList(children)
```

Answer (score 0):

`setRadioList` has to be used like this:

```
setRadioList(newList)
```

Spread operator splits array and sends each value as a separate parameter, so e.g. `setRadioList(...[1,2,3])` would become `setRadioList(1, 2, 3)` which is of course not correct.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_array_literals